# decanter framework doesnt work as expected in OpenDaylight Karaf shell

Tags: opendaylight

I was looking for logging frameworks available in OpenDaylight Controller.
Something similar to ELK stack.

I found apache decanter as a possible way to do this.
https://karaf.apache.org/manual/decanter/latest-1/

The problem is that it works fine with normal karaf shell but doesnt work so with the ODL karaf shell of Oxygen SR4 release.

As per the documentation,
https://karaf.apache.org/download.html#decanter-installation

```
feature:repo-add decanter
feature:install decanter-appender-elasticsearch
feature:install decanter-collector-log
feature:install decanter-collector-jmx
```

I tried the same in ODL karaf shell.
I downloaded the Oxygen-SR4 binary and started the karaf shell.

```
./karaf clean Apache Karaf starting up. Press Enter to open the shell now... 100% [========================================================================]

Karaf started in 0s. Bundle stats: 13 active, 13 total

    ________                       ________                .__  .__       .__     __       
    \_____  \ ______   ____   ____ \______ \ _____  ___.__.|  | |__| ____ |  |___/  |_     
     /   |   \\____ \_/ __ \ /    \ |    |  \\__  \<   |  ||  | |  |/ ___\|  |  \   __\    
    /    |    \  |_> >  ___/|   |  \|    `   \/ __ \\___  ||  |_|  / /_/  >   Y  \  |      
    \_______  /   __/ \___  >___|  /_______  (____  / ____||____/__\___  /|___|  /__|      
            \/|__|        \/     \/        \/     \/\/            /_____/      \/          


Hit '<tab>' for a list of available commands and '[cmd] --help' for help on a specific command. Hit '<ctrl-d>' or type 'system:shutdown' or 'logout' to shutdown OpenDaylight.

opendaylight-user@root>system:version 

4.1.6

opendaylight-user@root>feature:repo-add decanter Adding feature url

opendaylight-user@root>feature:install decanter-appender-elasticsearch
org.apache.karaf.features.core[org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl] : null
```

But the same thing works with plain apache karaf shell.

```
./karaf 
        __ __                  ____      
       / //_/____ __________ _/ __/      
      / ,<  / __ `/ ___/ __ `/ /_        
     / /| |/ /_/ / /  / /_/ / __/        
    /_/ |_|\__,_/_/   \__,_/_/         

  Apache Karaf (4.2.5)

Hit '<tab>' for a list of available commands and '[cmd] --help' for help on a specific command. Hit '<ctrl-d>' or type 'system:shutdown' or 'logout' to shutdown Karaf.

karaf@root()> feature:repo-add decanter Adding feature url mvn:org.apache.karaf.decanter/apache-karaf-decanter/RELEASE/xml/features karaf@root()>  feature:install decanter-appender-elasticsearch                                                                                                                                               karaf@root()>
```

Can anyone point out what is missing here because I feel the shell versions are similar?

Can you also suggest some other logging frameworks to process Karaf logs and data in OpenDaylight Controller(Oxygen SR4) something similar to ELK stack.

Answer (score 1):

we use decanter in upstream OpenDaylight system testing. the features we
install (using the featuresBoot variable in etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg are:

```
odl-jolokia,decanter-collector-jmx,decanter-appender-elasticsearch
```

but, we also configure the featuresRepositories to have:

```
mvn:org.apache.karaf.decanter/apache-karaf-decanter/1.0.0/xml/features
```

here is a [wiki page](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/CrossProject:Integration_Group:Harvesting_JVM_Metrics_Using_Decanter) with some extra info.

here is an example of us grabbing data to find [Mem Usage](https://logs.opendaylight.org/releng/vex-yul-odl-jenkins-1/netconf-csit-1node-scale-max-devices-only-fluorine/4/robot-plugin/log.html#s1-s2-t1-k8-k2) and we also
install elasticsearch which lets us see it as a [graph over time](https://logs.opendaylight.org/releng/vex-yul-odl-jenkins-1/netconf-csit-1node-scale-max-devices-only-fluorine/4/odl_1/heapmemory_1.png)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi. Can you please update the links in this comment? Getting page not found.